# Can I used OpenVPN server in US for Netflix in other countries?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Not sure if this is the right place to post this. If not, my apologies and kindly direct me to the right place.

Anyways, I have a relative in the States and asked her to setup an OpenVPN server in her desktop/laptop. I would then request for a client from her so I can setup my OpenVPN client outside of US so I can watch Netflix contents from the US :).

First question, is this legal? If not, then no need to discuss further as I would not want to put her in that kind of situation.

If it's ok, then the next question is "Will it work?". I plan on setting up a DD-WRT router at home and setup the OpenVPN client there so that all devices connected to the network will be on the same vpn including my android tv where I watch netflix,

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: just a couple comments: (1) from what I've read (eg see: https://www.tomsguide.com/features/are-netflix-vpns-legal ), no it's not illegal, but yes it's against the TOS (terms of service), but no they won't really do anything, but yes they may detect you're running a VPN and it won't even work; and (2) for a VPN server, won't you need a static IP address to connect to? Most desktop/laptops get their IP address dynamically assigned from the ISP, so you won't be able to connect your VPN client in the first place (I believe).

Comment: @michael i'm new to vpn and did not know i needed a static ip for a vpn server. thank you for the info. this answers my question. if you could post your comment as an answer, i'd gladly mark it as the answer.

Comment: my comments aren't really an answer beyond "try it & let me know if it works!", there'll certainly be some issues along the way. I once tried to set up a OpenVPN server (using a cloud service, where you can select the region the server is running) & had some problems getting DNS to go thru the VPN, which was really the whole problem I was trying to work around (different purpose though). Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it's off topic here. You can try our sister site [su].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Michael answered the question, but to answer your questions, you don't need static IP for a VPN, it should work just fine with dynamic as-well, you will just need to change the IP Address in the config in-case (your friend's) IP changes, or your friend will just send new config.

Your friend needs open ports, which some ISPs may filter. (Could be possible giving them a call, there may be some fee)

As for if Netflix would detect VPN, probably not as long as it's residental IP and you won't share the config file.

Comment: Please avoid answering off-topic questions. It only attracts more of them, and also makes extra work for moderators to clean up.